# Multiple CSS imports

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```
import style from './auth-input.module.css'
```

I'm using this in my authInput component, and I'm using this component 5 or 6 times,
it's better to try to import this CSS first and import it only once, or even if I'm importing the CSS 5 times it will be considered only one import?

Comment: Try to use proper grammar when asking questions as it allows others to understand what you’re trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome, please read the [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Correct, if you import the CSS module into your component, and then export your component and use it multiple times, the CSS will only be imported once.